# Perl: inserting array of arrays in into a array which is a value for a key

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures, hash-of-hashes

I have a need of inserting an array of arrays into an array.And this whole array is a value for a key in a hash.i meant hash should look like this:

```
"one"
[
  [
    1,
    2,
  [
    [
      3,
      4
    ],
    [
      5,
      6
    ]
  ]
]
]
```

where one is the key here and remaining part if the value of for that key in the hash.
observe that the array of arrays [3,4] and [5,6] is the third element in the actual array. the first two elements are 1 and 2.

I have written a small program for doing the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;

my %hsh;
my @a=[1,2];
my @b=[[3,4],[5,6]];
$hsh{"one"}=\@a;
push @{$hsh{"one"}},@b;
print Dumper(%hsh);
```

But this prints as below:

```
"one"
[
  [
    1,
    2
  ],   #here is where i see the problem.
  [
    [
      3,
      4
    ],
    [
      5,
      6
    ]
  ]
]
```

I can see that the array of arrays is not inserted into the array.
could anybody help me with this?

Comment: `[...]` creates an array reference, not an array. So `@a=[1,2]` creates an array of one element. This may be a source of your problem, but I'm not sure: The intendation of your expected data structure was confusing. `@a=(1,2)` would create an array of two elements. Are you sure you dont want `%hsh = ( one => [1, 2, [ 3, 4 ], [5, 6]] )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;

my %hsh;
my @a=(1,2); # this should be list not array ref
my @b=([3,4],[5,6]); # this should be list conatining array ref
push (@a, \@b); #pushing ref of @b
push (@{$hsh{'one'}}, \@a); #pushing ref of @a

print Dumper(%hsh);
```

Output:

```
"one"
[
  [
    1,
    2,
    [
      [
        3,
        4
      ],
      [
        5,
        6
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Updated:

```
my %hsh;
my @a=( 1,2 );
my @b=( [3,4],[5,6] );
push (@a, @b); # removed ref of @b
push (@{$hsh{'one'}}, @a); #removed ref of @a

print Dumper(\%hsh);

Output:
{
  "one" => [
    1,
    2,
    [
      3,
      4
    ],
    [
      5,
      6
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's it? You seem to have an an extra array. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, a note: Only pass scalars to `Dumper`. If you want to dump an array or hash, pass a reference.

Then there's the question of what you expect. You say you expect

```
[ [ 1, 2, [ [ 3, 4 ], [5, 6] ] ] ]
```

But I think you really expect

```
[ 1, 2, [ [ 3, 4 ], [5, 6] ] ]
```

Both errors have the same cause.

```
[ ... ]
```

means

```
do { my @anon = ( ... ); \@anon }
```

so

```
my @a=[1,2];
my @b=[[3,4],[5,6]];
```

is assigning a single element to `@a` (a reference to an anonymous array) an a single element to `@b` (a reference to a different anonymous array).

You actually want

```
my @a=(1,2);
my @b=([3,4],[5,6]);
```

So from

```
my %hsh;
$hsh{"one"}=\@a;
push @{$hsh{"one"}},@b;
print(Dumper(\%hsh));
```

you get

```
{
  "one" => [
    1,
    2,
    [
      3,
      4
    ],
    [
      5,
      6
    ]
  ]
}
```